# How to select the divs with the same class name using the jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code, I am trying to add an additional class "active" to all of the elements with the same class inside the experts-list div.

I want if someone clicks on the heading Athletes then an additional class "active" should be applied on Athlete One, Athlete Two, Athlete Three, and Athlete Four

and same with the other elements

```
<div class="expert-group-titles">
    <h3 class="athlete">Athletes</h3>
    <h3 class="actor">Actors</h3>
    <h3 class="business-man">Business Men</h3>
    <h3 class="chef">Chefs</h3>
    <h3 class="comedian">Comedians</h3>
    and list goes on...
</div>
<div class="experts-list">
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete One</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor One</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man One</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef One</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian One</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Four</div>
    and list goes one...
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: I would suggest you to read some articles/answers on this sites(there are many answers which will help you) and then edit your post with attempts you made and errors you got .  Start from here : [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method.

Answer (score 0):

1. This line of code will select all the elements with these two classes

   `var athletes = jQuery('.expert-box.athlete')`
2. Now you can add a **specific** class to the **athletes**

   `athletes.addClass('active')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(h3.athlete).on("click",function(){
    $("div.athlete").addClass("active")
})
```

Use on() to add click event listener to h3.athlete then do the function to add class active to dive.athlete using addClass method.

Comment: wouldn't it be inefficient for many designations?

Comment: By making array to hold all h3 we can make it working but this is the idea in general

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you move forward

```js
$("h3").each((i, elm) => {
  $(elm).click(function() {
    const clazz = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".experts-list .active").each((i, div) => {
      $(div).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".experts-list ." + clazz).each((i, div) => {
      $(div).addClass("active");
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expert-group-titles">
  <h3 class="athlete">Athletes</h3>
  <h3 class="actor">Actors</h3>
  <h3 class="business-man">Business Men</h3>
  <h3 class="chef">Chefs</h3>
  <h3 class="comedian">Comedians</h3>
</div>
<div class="experts-list">
  <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete One</div>
  <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Two</div>
  <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Three</div>
  <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Four</div>
  <div class="expert-box actor">Actor One</div>
  <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Two</div>
  <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Three</div>
  <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Four</div>
  <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man One</div>
  <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Two</div>
  <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Three</div>
  <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Four</div>
  <div class="expert-box chef">Chef One</div>
  <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Two</div>
  <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Three</div>
  <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Four</div>
  <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian One</div>
  <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Two</div>
  <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Three</div>
  <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there is more than one class?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something along these lines:

```
$.(".expert-group-titles > h3").click(function() {
    var clickedClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $.("expert-box " + clickedClass).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: what if there are multiple classes..wont work right?

Comment: Just saw you post, yes a removeClass or toggleClass would be needed to reset when other h3 elements are clicked

Comment: what if we add more than one class to h3 elemts?

Comment: http://gator3080.temp.domains/~unleadge/test/books/

here is the page

Answer (score 0):

You did not clear what exactly you want in question but you can do these two approach in my understanding:

`structure changes:`

- Change required class placement to `data-custom-class`.
- Add a class to your `expert-group-titles` items (here the class name is `group-title`).
- Add active class to `expert-group-titles` items.

*1. Append active to your group*

It means active other items of list even if first one is active too:

```js
(function ($) {

  'use strict';
  
  $(function () {
  
    var
      group = $('.expert-group-titles'),
      list = $('.experts-list'),
      //-----
      activeGroupCls = 'active-list',
      activeCls = 'active';
      
      group.find('.group-title').on('click', function () { 
        var current, klass, foundElements;
        current = $(this);
        
        klass = current.attr('data-custom-class');
        if(klass) {
          foundElements = list.find('[class*="' + klass + '"]');
          
          if(!current.hasClass(activeGroupCls)) {
            foundElements.addClass('active');
          } else {
            foundElements.removeClass('active');
          }
          
          current.toggleClass(activeGroupCls);
        }
      });
  
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.expert-group-titles, 
.experts-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.expert-group-titles .group-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.expert-group-titles .group-title:not(.active-list):hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.expert-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.active-list {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expert-group-titles">
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="athlete">Athletes</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="actor">Actors</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="business-man">Business Men</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="chef">Chefs</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="comedian">Comedians</h3>
</div>
<div class="experts-list">
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete One</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor One</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man One</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef One</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian One</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Four</div>
</div>
```

*2. Toggling your group*

It means just active clicked item:

```js
(function ($) {

  'use strict';
  
  $(function () {
  
    var
      group = $('.expert-group-titles'),
      groupItems = group.find('.group-title'),
      list = $('.experts-list'),
      listItems = list.find('.expert-box'),
      //-----
      activeGroupCls = 'active-list',
      activeCls = 'active';
      
      groupItems.on('click', function () { 
        var current, klass, foundElements;
        current = $(this);
        
        klass = current.attr('data-custom-class');
        if(klass) {
          foundElements = list.find('[class*="' + klass + '"]');
          
          // remove active class from group items and list items
          groupItems.removeClass(activeGroupCls);
          listItems.removeClass('active');
          
          if(!current.hasClass(activeGroupCls)) {
            foundElements.addClass('active');
          } else {
            foundElements.removeClass('active');
          }
          
          current.toggleClass(activeGroupCls);
        }
      });
  
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.expert-group-titles, 
.experts-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.expert-group-titles .group-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.expert-group-titles .group-title:not(.active-list):hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.expert-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.active-list {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expert-group-titles">
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="athlete">Athletes</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="actor">Actors</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="business-man">Business Men</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="chef">Chefs</h3>
    <h3 class="group-title" data-custom-class="comedian">Comedians</h3>
</div>
<div class="experts-list">
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete One</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box athlete">Athlete Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor One</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box actor">Actor Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man One</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box business-man">Business Man Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef One</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box chef">Chef Four</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian One</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Two</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Three</div>
    <div class="expert-box comedian">Comedian Four</div>
</div>
```